# Using RAII to simplify passing objects to other objects without copy

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, rvalue-reference, raii

```
extern class objx;
class Someclass
{
public:
    Someclass();
    void bar(objx);
    objx &om;
};

void foo()
{
    Someclass c;
    objx o;
    c.bar(o);

}

void Someclass::bar(objx& op)
{
//Save op in some local privatefield for later use
    om = op; //Here there should not be a copy;
}
```

Above code is wrong right? Because when o goes out of scope in foo() it is destructed. Is there a way not to copy o into a new object in bar? For example using bar(objx&& op) so we don't have to copy object or use smart pointers and for sure avoiding new/delete? And when bar() returns op would go out of scope and object gets destroyed.

[EDIT]
I could use a pointer instead. But the caller should keep track of the lifetime of the object. That is what I want to avoid.

[EDIT2]
The question is this: Is there a mechanism to keep a local variable alive as long as its reference is passed by reference to other functions (scopes)?

[EDIT4]
This code achieves same functionality using pointers:

```
#include <sstream>
class Someclass
{
public:
    Someclass() {  }
    void bar(std::stringstream *);
    std::stringstream *om;
};


void Someclass::bar(std::stringstream* op)
{
    om = op; 
}

int main()
{
    Someclass c;
    std::stringstream o;
    c.bar(&o);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you copying it into a new object? `bar` takes a reference, not a copy

Comment: Remember, since `foo` calls `bar`, `foo` can't end until after `bar` does.

Comment: @NathanOliver Bad example. Suppose bar saves it somewhere for later use.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes I am doing the thing that would work if compiler would knew it should keep the object alive.

Comment: Based on your comments the code is inadequate to reflect on what you are really trying to achieve. Please provide a [mcve] of what you are really trying to do and where the problem is

Comment: @Sia If you want to convey ownership, then you need a smart pointer.  Otherwise you can't assume you own the thing.

Comment: Edited the code.

Comment: *om = op; //Here there should not be a copy;* but there will be a copy since `om` is a value. Your example code is a bit of a mess I know you can't quite describe exactly what you want, that's kind-of the point of the question, but the bits you can describe need to be more precise.

Comment: Well the question is how to implement it so om gets a stable reference of o as if om is filled with some class constructor from the start.

Comment: Made a mess with my edits. Edited the code again.

Comment: @Sia "_Above code is wrong right?_" - Yes, it doesn't compile. Make a [mcve] that you can actually compile yourself and put that into the question.

Comment: OK. I wrote one wrong code which compiles. It shows what the problem is. I don't know if technically compiler could track the "o" when passed to other functions and as long as some block or object in scope is keeping a reference, keep the object alive. Using RAII and not by using garbage collection or active memory management stuff.

Comment: The declaration of `void bar(objx);` in the definition of `Someclass` says it'll take an `objx` by value. The definition `void Someclass::bar(objx& op)` says it'll take an `objx` reference. You probably only need _one_ example, but make it possible to compile it. Since you haven't accepted the answer you've gotten, I'm not sure what you want. If you want to transfer ownership, `move` it. If you are forced to use a class framework that does not support standard C++ stuff, like moving, wrap the object in an object that _does_ support moving.

Comment: I didn't accept the answer because it didn't answer my question which was using RAII to extend object lifetime when passing it around as reference is possible or not. I am concluding that it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone understood the importance of the RAII part in your question even even though it was in the title. Personally, I just kept reading the question and forgot the RAII part. The classes in your example does not seem to require any additional RAII-coding since they own automatic variables that manages their resources fine. The pointer in the second example may point to the object owned by the caller - but it'll be valid only until the object (owned by the caller) goes out of scope.

Comment: If you want to transfer ownership, you usually move-construct a new object (which is what eerorika suggested and you also thought about with `bar(objx&& op)`) - but if have a resource that does not support moving out-of-the-box, then you can add thin RAII wrapper around it, like a `unique_ptr`-like class that only has one "simple" task - to manage the resource and to provide methods to interact with the resource.

Answer (score 0):

> Above code is wrong right? Because when o goes out of scope in foo() it is destructed.

It depends on what "Save op in some local privatefield for later use" means. Making a copy is correct. Referring to the object would not be.

> Is there a way not to copy o into a new object in bar?

You can move into a new object instead.

> The receiver class is already instantiated.

Option 1: Don't do that.

Option 2: Assign the value member.

Comment: Move to what? To an uninitialized reference? Well seems we can't have one.

Comment: @Sia You can initialise a value member by moving.

Comment: Assigning to a value member will cause a copy operation.

Comment: @Sia Not if the type has move assignment operator and you asssign an rvalue.

Comment: Hmmm. That might be a solution in general. But in my case I cannot change the object implementation. It can be a MFC CList. And it won't use RAII.

Answer (score 0):

From the responses you kindly provided I concluded that it can be done if the passing object has the move semantics implemented in it.